# addition in javascript is resulting in an object

Tags: javascript, addition

I am tring to add 2 values together in a javascript application however when I try and do this the output I get is;

> Total Price £[object Object]116.96

Where **[object Object]** is the value I am trying to add to **116.96**
the code I am using to do the addition is bellow;

```
    document.getElementById("getTotal").addEventListener("click", function()
{
  var STotal = (($('#SeatPrice')+(subTotal)).toString());
  $('#total').text(STotal);
});
```

these are where the values for **'#seatPrice'** and **'#total'** are derived from

```
  $('#total').text(subTotal.toString());
  $('#SeatPrice').text((($('td.selected').length)+count)*pricing);
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to resolve this issue please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: Well you have a jQuery object, what part of that object do you want to add to the number? Is it an input, a div, a data attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies here: `var STotal = (($('#SeatPrice')+(subTotal)).toString());`

`$('#SeatPrice')` is a jquery function which returns an object - the html element you've searched for. So when you add that to your `subTotal`, you are adding the object to a string which, in javascript, will just create a string out of both.

You probably want to get the value of that element using something like `$('#SeatPrice').val()` or `$('#SeatPrice').text()`

Comment: just what i was looking for! Thanks @millerbr